# Jordan normal form of $\;\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & a & b \end{pmatrix},\; a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If possible, compute the Jordan normal form of

$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & a & b \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$  with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

In the case that $a,b=0$ the matrix already has Jordan normal form. However, the case that one or both, $a,b\neq0$ seems more complicated. How do I continue?

**Edit:** The eigenvalues are $b/2\pm\sqrt{b^2/4+a}$. Using this in order to find the kernel of $(A-\lambda_i)^j$ using Gaussian elimination doesn't seem like the intended approach. That is what I meant.

Comment: Simpler than what?

Comment: Simpler way than computing manually is having it calculated by a calculator...

Comment: If you want to find Jordon canonical form, then first try to find the eigenvalue and then the eigenspace!

Comment: Jordon block depends on G.M and A.M of an eigenvalue! I think without these, it is not possible to creat a block!

Comment: Clearly, Jordon canonical form varries with the values of a and b, first see, if you take a=0=b, then eigenvalue 0 has only one 3×3 block here, and which represents the Jordon canonical form, but if you take a=0, b some non zero real, then b have 1×1 block and 0 have 2×2 block!

Comment: So, I think it is not possible to creat one Jordon Normal form by taking arbitrary values of a,b!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can avoid computing generalized eigenvectors. Separate this into $3$ cases.

**Case 1:** $a = b = 0$. As you said, the matrix is already in Jordan form

**Case 2:** $a=0$, $b \neq 0$. The matrix is upper triangular, so we quickly see that its only eigenvalues are $0$ and $b$. The block associated with $b$ has size $1$, and the because the matrix $M$ has rank $2$, the block associated with $0$ has size $2$.

Now, if $a \neq 0$, then $M$ is block upper triangular with the form
$$
M = \left[\begin{array}{c|cc} 0&1&0\\ \hline 0&0&1\\0&a&b\end{array}\right]
$$

**Case 3:** If $a = -(b/2)^2 \neq 0$, then the lower-right block has a repeated eigenvalue, and its Jordan form consists of a single block. Thus, the overall Jordan form has a $0$ followed by a size-$2$ block.

**Case 4:**  In the remaining cases, the lower-right block has eigenvalues that are distinct and non-zero. Thus, $M$ has distinct eigenvalues, which means that its Jordan form is diagonal.

---

As an alternative, it would suffice to note that $M$ is the transpose of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) associated with the polynomial $p(t) = t^3 - bt^2 - at$. It follows that its Jordan form consists of a single block of maximal size for each of the roots of $p$.

Comment: I just noticed that the determinant of the lower right matrix only is negative if $a>0$. If $a<0$ we can still invert the lower right block but I'm not sure what that tells us about the eigenvalues.

Comment: That's a good point. We know that $0$ won't be a repeated eigenvalue, but we run into trouble if $a = -(b/2)^2$.

Comment: @user See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the approach with the companion matrix is really good.